# Webpack: Inclusion of .babelrc causes build to fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

OS: Windows 10 Pro
webpack: 2.5.1
node: 6.10.2

So, the inclusion of an .babelrc in the root of my project:

```html
{
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
}
```

causes builds (npm run build) to fail, with the following error message:

```html
ERROR in ./client/app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/d0475/Documents/Projects/learn-redux-graphql/client/app.js: Unexpected token (47:2)

  45 | */
  46 | render(
> 47 |   <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
     |   ^
  48 | 
  49 |     <Router history={history}>
  50 |       <Route path="/" component={App}>
```

What is the issue here?

My package.json is:

```html
"scripts": {
  "build:webpack": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
  "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:webpack",
  "test": "NODE_ENV=production mocha './tests/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register",
  "clean": "rimraf public",
  "start": "node devServer.js"
}
```

My webpack.config.prod is:

```html
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/app'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env',
      safe: true
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': "'production'"
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Flamingo City',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './index_template.ejs',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: '404.html' },
      { from: 'manifest.json' },
      { from: 'images', to: 'images' },
    ]),
    new OfflinePlugin({
      publicPath: '/',
      safeToUseOptionalCaches: true,
      caches: {
        main: [
          'main-*.js',
          'index.html',
        ],
        additional: [
          ':externals:'
        ],
        optional: [
          ':rest:'
        ]
      },
      externals: [
        '/'
      ],
      ServiceWorker: {
        navigateFallbackURL: '/',
        events: true
      },
      AppCache: {
        FALLBACK: {
          '/': '/offline-page.html'
        },
        events: true
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
    // js
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: ['babel-loader'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    },
    // CSS
    { 
      test: /\.styl$/, 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'stylus-loader'
      ]
    }
    ]
  }
};
```

My app.js is:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import 'babel-polyfill';
import { ApolloProvider, graphql, gql } from 'react-apollo';
import client from './apolloClient';
import App from './components/App';
import Single from './components/Single';
import PhotoGrid from './components/PhotoGrid';
import css from  './styles/style.styl';
import store, { history } from './store';
import Raven from 'raven-js';
import { sentry_url } from './data/config';

if(window) {
  Raven.config(sentry_url).install();
}

import * as OfflinePluginRuntime from 'offline-plugin/runtime';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  OfflinePluginRuntime.install();
}

render(
  <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid} />
        <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

npm-debug.log:

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.10.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0~prebuild: learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing
7 info lifecycle learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0~build: learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Projects\learn-redux-graphql\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\share\vim\vim74;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\d0475\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\d0475\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\d0475\AppData\Local\now-cli;C:\Users\d0475\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\d0475\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder
10 verbose lifecycle learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Projects\learn-redux-graphql
11 silly lifecycle learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run clean && npm run build:webpack' ]
12 silly lifecycle learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
14 verbose stack Error: learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0 build: `npm run clean && npm run build:webpack`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Projects\learn-redux-graphql
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
19 error node v6.10.2
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0 build: `npm run clean && npm run build:webpack`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the learn-redux-graphql@1.0.0 build script 'npm run clean && npm run build:webpack'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the learn-redux-graphql package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     npm run clean && npm run build:webpack
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs learn-redux-graphql
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls learn-redux-graphql
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Same issue here. Did you finally solve this?

Comment: @Towfiq See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned use of the .babelrc file, and in my package.json instead I do the following:

```html
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    ......
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2015",
      "stage-0"
    ],
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "plugins": [
          [
            "transform-async-to-generator"
          ],
          [
            "transform-object-rest-spread"
          ],
          [
            "transform-react-display-name"
          ],
          [
            "react-transform",
            {
              "transforms": [
                {
                  "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
                  "imports": [
                    "react"
                  ],
                  "locals": [
                    "module"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
                  "imports": [
                    "react",
                    "redbox-react"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "production": {
        "plugins": [
          [
            "transform-async-to-generator"
          ],
          [
            "transform-object-rest-spread"
          ],
          [
            "transform-react-display-name"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```